# Using htaccess to redirect user profiles

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am creating a social networking site. Using .htaccess I have successfully removed .php extensions from urls but I am not able to redirect **domain.com/u.php?username=[username]** to **domain.com/u/[username]**. Following is my .htaccess file:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

DirectoryIndex home.php
```

I have seen many examples and codes in stackoverflow but all of them redirect from **domain.com/user.php?username=[username]** to **domain.com/[username]**. But this would affect my website since I have removed .php extensions and I might end up with name clash. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put this code in your root htaccess

```
DirectoryIndex home.php
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# redirect /u.php?username=XXX to /u/XXX
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/u\.php\?username=([^&\s]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ u/%1? [R=301,L]

# hide php extension (if file exists)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/(.+)\.php(?:\?|\s) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1? [R=301,L]

# internally rewrite /u/XXX to /u.php?username=XXX
RewriteRule ^u/([^/]+)$ u.php?username=$1 [L]

# internally rewrite (if it exists) extensionless to php extension
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: Well this works fine but I am facing a problem. Page content is not loading properly :(

Comment: That's a normal behaviour since you create a virtual directory (`/u/`) and you're using *relative* paths instead of **absolute** paths for all your html resources. Add a leading slash for all resources links or add this tag after `<head>`: `<base href="/">`

Comment: Could you show me an example of one of your links ? Such as a css for instance

Comment: Originally: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/globals/plugins/blueimp-gallery/css/blueimp-gallery.min.css">` but I changed it according to what you said `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/globals/plugins/blueimp-gallery/css/blueimp-gallery.min.css">` but still both won't work

Comment: When I see chrome console log, its actually loads, `localhost/assets/....` but it is supposed to load `localhost/myproject/assets/....`

Comment: Oh right, you didn't mention your project was in a subfolder. I guess you adapted the htaccess code since it shouldn't be working for a subfolder. Anyway, you must have either "/myproject/" before each resources links or (if you don't want to replace all links) you can add `<base href="/myproject/">` after `<head>` html tag

Comment: Thank you so much :) Finally works but when I transfer my files to my domain, should i change it back `<base href="/">` ?

Comment: If your project is in root folder, then yes of course. Glad it helped, you're welcome